# how to pass array of to find in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a conversation schema in which one of the value is this:   `participants:[]` .
It is an array of user strings.

I want to get the conversation based on the array which contains user ids. Right now I am doing this:

```
const selectedConversation = await Conversation.find({
      userIds: { $in: participants },
    });
```

But the issue with this is that it returns a first conversation in which atleast one user id matches.

participants array look like this  `["user id 1","user id 2","user id 3"]` , same with `userIds`

Any workarounds for this one please?

Comment: Can you add an example of your DB and how is the `participants` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the userIds as your id field in your schema. Most probably it is _id. Final code will look like this:

```
const selectedConversation = await Conversation.find({
      _id: { $in: participants },
});
```

Further reading:
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/